# Weblogic to JBoss JNDI - JMS queue Consumer and Publisher

Tags: jboss, jms, weblogic, jndi

I am working on an example where a JMS queue is hosted on a JBoss EAP 6 instance (one for Request and another for Response). I also have an application running on a Weblogic managed server.

I would like to setup a mechanism that allows applications running on Weblogic to be able to consume messages that are added on the Request queue hosted on JBoss. Also the applications should be able to publish messages to the Request queue (also hosted on JBoss)

I read about **Foreign JNDI Providers** in Oracle Documentation, and most of the examples I find are Weblogic to Remote Weblogic connections and Weblogic to Remote LDAP. My concern is around the difference in in the implementations  on *javax.naming.InitialContext* for Weblogic and JBoss (whether it would be compatible).

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the JNDI implementation nor the JMS implementation from JBoss EAP will be compatible with Weblogic. However, that shouldn't be a problem as both can be used by the same application given the right configuration.

Consider a standalone JMS application that consume a message from JMS provider X and sends a message to JMS provider Y. It would first use the JNDI implementation from JMX provider X to lookup the JMS connection factory and queue. That lookup would return the proper JMS implementation objects from provider X. The application would use those objects to consume a message from the queue. Then it would use the JNDI implementation from JMX provider Y to lookup the second JMS connection factory and queue. That lookup would return the proper JMS implementation objects from provider Y. As long as the JNDI InitialContext properties are all correct for each of the lookups and all the implementation classes are on the the application's classpath then everything will work without issue.

The situation in Weblogic is similar. You simply need to configure the foreign JNDI provider with the right properties, put the right implementation classes on the classpath, and then use all the right names in your JNDI lookups.